# Trying to build AMD modules with Webpack — getting "Cannot resolve module 'exports'" error

Tags: webpack

I am trying to introduce Webpack in a project that has been using AMD modules with Require.js. The relevant part of the project structure is this:

[image]

(i.e. the project root folder contains a `js` folder with all the application scripts, whose entry point is main.js, and also a `tools` folder with `npm_modules` and the gulp tasks that I am building)

*(and yeah, I know that it would be simpler to have `npm_modules` and `gulpfile` in the root of the project, but that's the structure that I have)*

So I am trying to build a js bundle out of the AMD modules into which the app is divided. To simplify, let’s say the main.js file has the following code:

```js
define([
    'jquery'
], function (
    $
) {
    'use strict';

    console.log($);
});
```

which means that I need to import `jquery` from `./js/libs/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js`

So here is the webpack config (`webpack.js` file on the tree diagram) that I wrote:

```js
var path = require('path');

var appModulesPath = path.resolve('../js'); // gulpfile’s process is run in ./tools folder
var nodeModulesPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules');
console.log(appModulesPath, ' and ', nodeModulesPath); // I confirm that paths are correct

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, '../../'),
    debug: false,
    resolve: {
        root: [appModulesPath, nodeModulesPath],
        alias: {
            'jquery': 'libs/vendors/jquery/dist/jquery',
        },
        extensions: ['.js']
    },
    entry: ['./js/main'],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '../../js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /jquery/, loader: 'exports?$'},
        ]
    }
};
```

but when I try to run the task I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ../js/main.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'exports' in /path/to/project/root/folder/js
 @ ../js/main.js 1:0-9:2
```

If I understand the error correctly, Webpack tries and fails to use the `exports-loader`. But I have it installed, and it sits in the `node_modules` folder. Is it that Webpack doesn't know where to look for `node_modules`? But I am resolving the root in the config, and when I log out the paths that I pass to `resolve.root`, they are: `/path/to/project/root/js` and `/path/to/project/root/tools/node_modules`. Why doesn’t Webpack pick `exports-loader` up?

I am out of ideas. Could you please help?

Comment: you should mark your own answer as accepted :)

Comment: done :-) 
(wow, there's a limit to how short a comment can be! a simple "done" didn't cut it)

Comment: Great! Haha yeah.. to prevent: "Thanks"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bah! To spend half an hour describing the problem and then, in a final desperate search attempt to find an answer! :-)

The solution was to use [resolveLoader](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolveloader).

Thanks to [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1083) discussion on Github.

Comment: what does this answer even mean?